# Simple Railing follow a curve with sharp angles

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

it's a problem that i didn't never find a proper solution for. I'm trying to make a simple railing following a 3d curve. Simple as that. So the setup is the usual, object -> array -> curve.
BUT. My path has sharp conrners. Like a balcony. And the curve in total is quite long. Is there an easy way/addon to do this simple task. I sometime use sketchup and it has a fantastic tool that do this (shape bender).
Maybe i can try with face instancing and screw modifier (for the z-up align) but not sure it will work properly.

So the problem are two:
1 - Easy way to bend shape along 3d curve with sharp corners
2 - keep the object z-aligned so it's perpendicular to the ground and not the object.

Already tried:

- Boost the curve resolution.
- Subdivided the curve
- Subdivided the railing

Not help.
So many many thanks to everyone's help!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that it is what you want but for the top shape you can create a curve that you set to 2D, with Handle Type > Vector so that it has orthogonal angles, and give it a square curve as bevel object

Comment: thanks for the reply! The curve must be a 3D curve, unfortunately.

Comment: yes, maybe i don't properly understand. Also the curve for the top shape should be a 3d curve, (it has x,y,z) and i prefer have an array+curve setup for future changes. is this that you mean? Seems impossible to me that there isn't an easy way/addon  to achieve this, so important feature for my routines. But maybe it's only my lack of knowledge.

Comment: yes I think you've understood, I would have done it with curve set to 2D with another orthogonal curve as profile, then convert to mesh for further changes (for example on Z axis). I hope someone will find a proper answer.

Comment: Hi all, i'm again on the same question because didn't find an easy and fast solution. Is there an easy solution to make a simple railing follow a 3d curve with th z-up? I looked to geo node too, but i'm still trying understanting how it works properly. Many many thanks!!